# Прервать процесс по таймауту в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в Python готовое решение (уверен что есть не могу найти) для такой задачи.
Нужно по таймауту кильнуть процесс. Тоесть должно работать как вот такой костыль:

```py
import os
import signal
import time
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process


def o(time_limit: int = 0):
    start = datetime.now()
    while (datetime.now() - start).seconds <= time_limit:
        time.sleep(.1)
    else:
        os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)
    print(f'\n{datetime.now() - start}')


def main():
    start = datetime.now()
    while (datetime.now() - start).seconds < 30:
        print(f'\r{(datetime.now() - start).seconds}', end='')
        time.sleep(1)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_start = datetime.now()
    print(os.getpid())
    p = Process(target=o, args=(20,))
    p.start()
    if main():
        p.kill()
    else:
        p.join()
        print()
```

Comment: BTW а зачем второй импорт ос в функции о?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, это мусор. Не убрал. Ща почищу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каноничное решение это прерывание на SIGALARM. Но оно не работает с асинхронным кодом.

Можно так, чтоб не засорять блокировками маин

```
def timeout(p, t):
    p.join(t)
    p.kill()
    p.join()
    
p = Process(target=o, args=(20,))
Thread(target=timeout, args=(p, 30)).start()
```

Comment: Если это каким то образом решает задачу, которая стоит передо мной (`Господа, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в Python готовое решение`), могу Вас попросить поподробней немного?

Comment: решения готового нет, но есть простые.